# How to prepare regex which accept 10 or more but not 0 and 1 + iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, regex

I am facing a problem in building a regex. I have strings with foods and respective frequencies, which I want to display.

Code:

```
NSString *strNames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"apple 12 orange 10 mango 1 rice 0"]; // Suppose 
NSCharacterSet *allowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789 "] invertedSet];
NSString *resultString = [[strNames componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:allowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

output:

> Printing description of resultString: *apple 2 orange  mango  rice*

when I am using this regex

```
NSCharacterSet *allowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "] invertedSet];
```

the output is:

> Printing description of resultString: *apple 12 orange 10 mango 1 rice
>   0*

but my requirement is 
***apple 12 orange 10 mango rice***

so please suggest any idea or solution.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to remove single digit integer numbers enclosed with spaces from a string?

Answer (score 0):

Note that your input imlies you have a space separated string where you need to remove single-digit non-whitespace chunks. You might split the string with spaces, then filter out all the unwanted strings with a mere `\d` regex and join the "words" into the final results:

```
NSString *s = @"apple 12 orange 10 mango 1 rice 0";
NSArray *comps = [s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSPredicate *oneDigitRx = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '\\d'"];
NSMutableArray *words = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSString *comp in comps) {
  if(![oneDigitRx evaluateWithObject:comp]) {
    [words addObject:comp];
  }
}
NSString *result = [words componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSLog(result);
```

See [this Objective C demo](https://ideone.com/UNcpCD)

You might also try a regex to directly replace the single digits:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *s = @"apple 12 orange 10 mango 1 rice 0";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<!\\S)\\d(?!\\S)\\s*" options:nil error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:s options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(modifiedString);
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/gjBjRB)

The `(?<!\S)\d(?!\S)\s*` regex matches a digit that is either enclosed with whitespaces or is at the start/end of the string. The `\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces to remove any if present after the digit.

If your single digit numbers can be enclosed with any non-word chars, you can use a more sophisticated [`@"(?<![\\d.])\\b\\d\\b(?!\\.\\d)\\s*"`](https://regex101.com/r/Zx4kxO/1) regex.